# How to receive PDF's in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, b2b

I have a simple system in place using BizTalk where I can receive AS2 X12 810 messages through BizTalk . BizTalk accepts those messages, translates it to an XML format, and sends it over to a web service. I have a requirement that every message received should have 1 or more PDF files that are associated with it.

How can I make this happen?

Questions:

1. Can I simply receive PDF files through BizTalk?
2. How can I receive PDF files through BizTalk?
3. What would be a good implementation for accepting an 810 invoice + attachments?

Thank you a million for any help. Getting help with BizTalk is incredibly difficult, so I really appreciate all time spent reading/discussing/time put forth to help.

Comment: Have you checked http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richardbpi/archive/2005/10/27/485696.aspx might be a tad old but I'd think the principles are the same?

Comment: I came across this post, and I took it as not useful because the pictures were gone. But after actually reading it I have something to try. Do you think I can make this work with AS2 on top ?

Comment: Not certain about that but worth a try. Isn't AS2 "just" an envelope for data? Should be able to send binaries as attachments or something like that.

Comment: Will the .pdf's come in the same AS2 request?  Meaning, are they posted at the same time?

Comment: It would be preferred for them to come in the same AS2 message. That is possible? How can I do that?

@Jontatas Yeah I think so. I'm researching this now. I don't have any clue on how to attach any kind of file to an AS2 msg

Comment: Yes it is apparently do-able to both send AS2 messages with attachments and receive AS2 message with attachments.  See this thread here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72ae689b-8c4f-47f6-85ce-e1098393b0bb/attachments-over-as2?forum=biztalkediandas2

Comment: Thank you for that post @Dijkgraaf but unfortunately all of that goes over my head. The part where it says to add attachments as "parts" using AS2 send encoder confuses me.

Comment: You can get the pictures for that first blog here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140517144545/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richardbpi/archive/2005/10/27/485696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To receive binary files of any type in Biztalk set the message type within the orchestration to **System.Xml.XmlDocument**.

Don't use any kind of dissassembler on the message as it comes in. A PassThru pipeline will work fine.

Biztalk will effectively ignore the contents of the message in this case and you can route it as normal.